# Replacing line of text cointing using sed

Tags: linux, sed, command-line, grep

```
's/document\.querySelector\(\'\.popup\'\)\.classList\.add\(\'active\'\)/document\.querySelector\(\'\.popup\'\)\.classList\.add\(\'noactive\'\)/' design.js
```

I'm trying to replace
`document.querySelector('.popup').classList.add('active')`
by
`document.querySelector('.popup').classList.add('noactive')`

Comment: Start by reading up on POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax.

Comment: And note you can't escape single quotes in a single-quoted string in shell. *A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="document.querySelector('.popup').classList.add('active')"
sed "s/\\(document\\.querySelector('\\.popup')\\.classList\\.add('\\)\\(active')\\)/\1no\2/g" <<< "$s"
# => document.querySelector('.popup').classList.add('noactive')
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/H0vqcc). The regex is POSIX BRE compliant and matches

- `\(document\.querySelector('\.popup')\.classList\.add('\)` - Group 1 (`\1`):  a literal `document.querySelector('.popup').classList.add('` text
- `\(active')\)` - Group 2 (`\2`): a literal `active')` text.

Note the capturing groups in a POSIX BRE regex are set with `\(...\)`. The literal dots need escaping and since the double quoted literal is used, the backslashes are doubled (and no need to escape single quotes).